# Getting UNAUTHORISED ERROR 401 - Sendgrid API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to perform actions on sendgrid lists via their API.
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#List-All-Lists-GET

I'm using this to set up my code however I'm getting Error 401 UNAUTHORISED when performing the request via $http in my Angular app. 
I tried making the same request in Python and that seemed to working fine though.

```
var head = {'Authorization': 'Bearer SG.PE-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'};
var sgUrl = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists";

self.$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : sgUrl,
    headers : head,
}).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    alert(1);
}, function myError(response) {
    alert(0);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you see any errors in your console after the request?

Comment: Yes, Error 401: Unauthorized. 
That'll all.

Comment: Maybe your token is expired, try to request another one

Comment: The API key is alright. Tried creating new ones too.

Comment: unfortunately HTTP GET Ajax requests are not allowed from client side in sendgrid API.

Comment: @Niladri Any other way of using the API on client side

Comment: @ShivamDhawan as per my knowledge only Node.js sdk are supported for V3 version of API.

Comment: @Niladri Okay.. Thank you for the help.. ✌️

Comment: @ShivamDhawan another option is if you are using firebase cloud functions in angular then you can send mail using Sendgrid. https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Tutorials/Zapier/sending_when_new_firebase_child_records_added.html